# pandas dataframe with time stamp - extract only time

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

How can I extract only the time from time field value represented as unix time in a pandas dataframe.

i.e from 1630236142.942 which is August 29, 2021 11:22:22.942 AM, I'd like to have only the 11:22:22.942

EDIT:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['time'], unit='s').time()
```

is generating an error `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute time`

Comment: Could you add more information on the dataframe, maybe? There's no much information on how you df looks like.

Comment: Do you need `pd.to_datetime(df['time'], unit='s').dt.time` ?

Comment: @jezrael didn't got your comment

Comment: If working for you modified your answer with `.dt` and without `()`

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
from datetime import datetime

# this line converts the string object in Timestamp object
df['DateTime'] = [datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') 
                  for d in df["DateTime"]]

# this line extract time from Timestamp object
df['Time'] = [datetime.strptime(d, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").time()
              for d in df['DateTime']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```py
pd.to_datetime(1630236142.942, unit='s').time()
```

Also you can do this for column:

```py
# thanks for finding mistake
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], unit='s').dt.time
```

Comment: I'm getting an error: `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute time`

Comment: Sorry. Try this: df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], unit='s').dt.time